# how to alter the click option in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, themes, tumblr

Firstly I would like to state that I am useless at jQuery,
so the problem I am facing is that I have no idea how to code the click
at the moment to close the popup you need to click on the button, but I would like for the popup to close when you click outside of it you can see the popup here http://doctorsafraid.tumblr.com/   (click the triangle then the links).

Thisis the script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //
//When you click on a link with class of poplight and the href starts with a #
$('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
    var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
    var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size
    //Pull Query & Variables from href URL
    var query= popURL.split('?');
    var dim= query[1].split('&');
    var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value
    //Fade in the Popup and add close button
    $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/r720j6.png" class="btn_close" alt="close" /></a>');
    $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend;
    //Define margin for center alignment (vertical   horizontal) - we add 80px to the height/width to accomodate for the padding  and border width defined in the css
    var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 90) / 2;
    var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 90) / 2;
    //Apply Margin to Popup
    $('#' + popID).css({
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });
    //Fade in Background
    $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
    $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}) is used to fix the IE Bug on fading transparencies
    return false;
});
//Close Popups and Fade Layer
$('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
    $('#fade , .thepopup').fadeOut(function() {
        $('#fade, a.close').remove();  //fade them both out

    });
    return false;
});

});
</script>
```

What should I alter?

Comment: Check if this can be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091287/jquery-ui-dialog-close-when-click-outside

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work for you. I use something similar but without jQuery ;)

```
function closePopup(e) {
    // Close the popup here

    // Remove the listener to prevent problems
    $('html, body').unbind('click', closePopup);
}

$('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function () {
    // Your code here

    // Add click evenetlistener on hole page
    $('html, body').click(closePopup);
});

// Prevent the listener for the hole page
$("#popupContainer").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is my edited version. It includes your code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //
        //When you click on a link with class of poplight and the href starts with a #
        $('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function () {
            var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
            var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size
            //Pull Query & Variables from href URL
            var query = popURL.split('?');
            var dim = query[1].split('&');
            var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value
            //Fade in the Popup and add close button
            $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number(popWidth) }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/r720j6.png" class="btn_close" alt="close" /></a>');
            $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number(popWidth) }).prepend;
            //Define margin for center alignment (vertical   horizontal) - we add 80px to the height/width to accomodate for the padding  and border width defined in the css
            var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 90) / 2;
            var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 90) / 2;
            //Apply Margin to Popup
            $('#' + popID).css({
                'margin-top': -popMargTop,
                'margin-left': -popMargLeft
            });
            //Fade in Background
            $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
            $('#fade').css({ 'filter': 'alpha(opacity=80)' }).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}) is used to fix the IE Bug on fading transparencies

            // add click listener to hole page
            $('html, body').click(closePopup);

            return false;
        });
        //Close Popups and Fade Layer
        $('a.close, #fade').live('click', closePopup);

        // Prevent the listener for the hole page
        $("#popupContainer").click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        function closePopup(e) {
            $('#fade , .thepopup').fadeOut(function () {
                $('#fade, a.close').remove();  //fade them both out

            });

            $('html, body').unbind('click', closePopup);

            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I literally have no idea where to put that, I really suck at this :(